# If $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and has a maximum or minimum at $x$ then $f'(x) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be an open set and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which attains a maximum or minimum at $x \in U$. I want to prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f'(x) = 0$.

I sketched the following proof. Let $h \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be fixed and $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x +(-\epsilon,\epsilon)h \subseteq U$. Define $\varphi: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ by setting $\varphi(t) = f(x+th)$. Notice that $\varphi$ attains a maximum or minimum at $t=0$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, we must have:
$$f'(x)h = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\varphi(t) -\varphi(0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\varphi(t+s)-\varphi(s)}{t}\bigg{|}_{s=0} $$
and, since $\varphi$ attains a maximum or a minimum at $t=0$:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\varphi(t+s)-\varphi(s)}{t}\bigg{|}_{s=0} = \frac{d\varphi}{dt}\bigg{|}_{t=0} = 0$$
as wished.

However, I'm unsure about the passage:
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\varphi(t) -\varphi(0)}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\varphi(t+s)-\varphi(s)}{t}\bigg{|}_{s=0} $$
It seems that I'm assuming $f$ differentiable not only at $x$ but on a more general set which inclused $x+(-\epsilon,\epsilon)h$. Am I correct? If so, how can we fix the argument or prove the result in another way?

Comment: You don't really need the '$s$'. We have $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\varphi(t)-\varphi(0)}{t}=\frac{d\varphi}{dt}\rvert_{t=0}$ by definition of $\frac{d\varphi}{dt}$

Comment: Can you say why you feel you need to introduce $s$ at all? [You're right that what you've written assumes more differentiability than the hypothesis gives you.] You seem to  introduce it in one line and dismiss it in the next.

Comment: @leoli1 you are right. I don't know why I added the $s$ but now I realized this was not needed indeed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x)$ is a maximum and $f'(x)$ exists, then we have that for all $u \in \mathbb R^m$,
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + tu) - f(x)}{t} = a(u)
$$

Since the limit exists, we can consider sequences $t_n \to 0$:
$$
a = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x + t_nu) - f(x)}{t_n}.
$$
If we pick a sequence where $t_n > 0$ then we have that $a \leq 0$ since $f(x)$ is a maximum and so
$$
\frac{f(x + t_nu) - f(x)}{t_n} \leq 0.
$$
If we pick a sequence $t_n < 0$ then we have instead
$$
\frac{f(x + t_nu) - f(x)}{t_n} \geq 0.
$$
So we conclude that $a \in (-\infty, 0] \cap [0, \infty)$, so is $0$.